# Is it possible to hide a @property in a subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app subclasses `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and uses all of its properties **except for** `minimumLineSpacing`. To avoid confusion, I'd like to be able to "hide" `minimumLineSpacing` from the outside, so it looks like my subclass doesn't even support it. Is this possible?

Comment: it is not possible to hide anything in parent class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can. Kind of. You can mark it with `__attribute__((unavailable))`, which will cause the compiler to throw an error if you use it. However, the property will still be accessible if your object is cast to its superclass type, as this is a compile-time-only thing.

```
@interface MyClass : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minimumLineSpacing __attribute__((unavailable));
@end
```

Comment: We can use `UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE` instead of `__attribute__((unavailable))`. It's more like syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually hide it. You could of course overwrite the getter and setter and prevent the acutal value from beeing changed, if that is of importance. But they will always exist and be visible.

Comment: Indeed, it's impossible to hide the inherited; it would break polymorphism.